# Dynamic widget creation

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a simple todo application. One issue is that I can't figure out how to make my program create new "LineEdits" dynamically for writing down tasks. Here is a picture of what I have made already:

todo application image:
[image: todo application image]

What you see in the image is a series of hard coded lineEdits which is not a good way of creating the app.

**So my question is:**

What do you recommend is the best way to dynamically allow the user to add new lines (lineEdits) in this app?

**App Layout:**

The app consists of one main "QScrollArea" (to allow the user to scroll down and up if needed). Inside of the "QScrollArea" is a "QVBoxLayout" (basically a vertical layout). Inside the "QVBoxLayout" are many "QHBoxLayout" (horizontal layouts) and each of them contain one "lineEdit" and one "checkbox".

I still haven't added any code to my app because I wanted to know how I can solve this issue first. I have only created what you see in the image using the "Qt Designer".

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically add new lines (`QLineEdit` instances) to the list, here's a sketch (check details in the Qt documentation):

- put a button somewhere, "Add a line"
- attach to the `clicked` signal
- in the slot attached to the signal, create a new QLineEdit with parent the scroll area, and add it to the vbox

If you're asking about user-interface-design principles (e.g. "is a button labeled 'add a line' a good idea?" that's probably not for C++ people to advise on).

Comment: Thank you. Just two more questions : 1-How can I create a new "QLineEdit" and specify the parent of it? 2- I don't understand what you meant by design principles, if you believe that this is a bad idea by all means correct me and point me to the right direction. I am always open to recommendations. ( since I am a noob) :D

Comment: @Saviz, To 1. I believe he is referring to dynamic creation of the QLineEdit object. You could have something like array of QLineEdits that get allocated based the previous ones getting labelled with text. Once allocated, add the QLineEdit to your layout.
2-By design principle he refers to User Experience. In other words, "what is a UI design that looks good and easy to use" for example. That is a totally different philosophy that doesn't have much to do with development and a lot of the times could depend on the platform and and methods of interaction available on the target device

Comment: That's right! My apologies I didn't get it at first. :)